# "material-table" - Is there a way to seperate filtering from the table . - ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-table

Hey guys i don't know if this is possible , but i would like to have the filtering with the dropdown on a seperate component outside of the table , but still to filter the current table . Is this thing possible ? And if it is can i have an example ?[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can change the `data` prop of the material-table. See this simple [example](https://codesandbox.io/embed/frosty-hooks-uvezj) where an separate button component changes the sorting of the content.

1. Store the data in the wrapping components state.
2. Render the filter and the material-table component.
3. Change the state (data) when the filter changes (you will have to implement the filter logic).

Comment: Probably this will work . Now i have to create a dropdown element with the data init .  I will let you know if i have succseed . Thanks for the headsup mate !